# command line arguments to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I've read several related questions here but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. 
Here's my script (simple.js):

```
    var x = process.argv[2]
    console.log(x);
```

now when I type in the REPL

```
    .load simple.js Hello
```

the REPL answers

```
 Failed to load:simple.js Hello
```

but I've done this (simple2.js):

```
    console.log(process.argv);
```

and when I .load this file in REPL it answers

```
    > console.log(process.argv);
    [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe' ]
    undefined
```

Comment: Just tested it: I don't think the REPL `.load` is designed for this sort of thing. You probably have to use the standard `node simple.js Hello` in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass command line args to `.load`. The second case didn't fail because you didn't pass one.

If you want to use cmdline args, just use the OS terminal and enter `node simple.js Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

`.load` inside the Node REPL just loads a file. From the [REPL docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys) it looks like the primary use case of `.load` is to restore a REPL session that was saved using `.save`.

In your succesful example its simply showing what `process.argv` is set to when you ran `node` in your terminal